# Text has to fetched from a edit text and displayed in an edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

I have 2 edit texts. I will type a message in one of the edit text.  On clicking the button, I want it to be displayed in the other edit text box. How to do that??I am new to android. Please help.

Comment: it's vary basic ...what you tried ?

Comment: Ya it is basic...!! ..In onclick listener of button I wrote edittext2 = edittext1.getstring();

Comment: should be edittext2 .setText(edittext1.getText());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach you may try is by using `TextWatcher` i.e. implement TextChangedListener(). Gives you better control.

Answer (score 2):

It should be as simple as this. In the `OnClickListener` of your button do this :

```
editText2.setText(editText1.getText().toString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(<layoutResID>)
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(<Buton _id>);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(<EditText _id>);
                 EditText e2 = (EditText)findViewById(<EditText _id>);

                 e2.setText(e1.getText());

            }
        })
    }
```